# How do I add unique IDs to dynamically created input fields in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I am using javascript to create input fields dynamically with a limit of 10 allowed on my form.  What I need to do to ensure these fields are submitted to the correct place is give them the right ID.  My question is how do I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    var num = new Number;
    var newNum = num + 1;        

    /*if (x = max_fields) {
        alert("You can't add anymore fields.")   
    }
    */

    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="clonedInput"><input id="" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

It would be nice for each input box to have an ID like "data_item_1" , "data_item_2", "data_item_3" etc etc.  I'm not sure on how to do this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use global variable like `x` to generate unique ids. You could have used `x`  but as you are decrementing `x` so you may need to use separate variable.

```
$(wrapper).append('<div class="clonedInput"><input id="data_item_'+itemIndex+'"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
```

You code would be like

```
var itemIndex = 2;
$(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

          $(wrapper).append('<div class="clonedInput"><input id="data_item_'+ itemIndex++ +'"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `itemIndex` here?

Comment: Thanks for this, makes sense I think I was overengineering what I was doing.  Do you know how I can set the value of the initial text box id as the ID's start at 2 onwards?

Comment: Initialize itemIndex  = 2?

Comment: Lovely, all working now, many thanks.  My initial approach was wrong and this has a much cleaner way.  Over thinking my concept a bit.

Comment: Whilst this approach works I have noticed that removing a text input can throw the numbering out of sync and it's important that it remains between 1 and 10 only.  Remvoing inputs and readding them can also cause ID duplication.  Is there a way around this or should I perhaps raise a seperate question?

Comment: Do not decrement the itemIndex to avoid duplication that is what I already suggested. To ensure you have 1-10 inputs you can use the x that you already have.

Comment: If sequence of input is required then you can use jQuery index function and there are many other ways to do that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line inside the click event

```
$(wrapper).append('<div class="clonedInput"><input id="data_item_'+x+'" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

Comment: Ids will be duplicate if user deletes and items let say if user added 3 items and deleted 2nd items and `x--` set value to 3 and now when user add new items two fields have same id (data_item_3) as per your answer;